# Classic ASP to MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, asp-classic

Right - going to be blunt. I've used classic ASP for what seems like an age and a half.

I would like to start making use of the .NET framework and MVC in particular seems to be something that is mentioned a lot.

The question is how do I make that transition? Are there any good tutorials? Any decent books?

Comment: I read and created the sport store exampel from Pro ASP NET MVC2 Framework second Edition to learn MVC. Lots of good info but mixes in unit testing, mocking and MEF which isnt specifically relevant to mvc so there may be better books

Comment: Its good for you to directly learn asp.net mvc without understanding webforms. MVC can be compared to ASP meaning they are completely stateless and MVC has different pipeline and separation, however if model gets passed to view, it is same as scripting out ASP page. And regarding tutorials/books, look into asp.net website.

Comment: +1 for Pro ASP.NET MVC4 book. Make sure to become familiar with JavaScript and client-side libraries like jQuery and the sort. Read Blogs, check the asp.net website, subscribe to pluralsight.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly learn ASP.NET MVC 4 from the 
[asp.net](http://www.asp.net) site.

For myself, learn mvc and entity framework from [Contoso University](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc) example.

Answer (score 1):

Try out most of basic terms of MVC pattern applied to classic ASP in article:  Classic ASP and MVC
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/585883/Classic-ASP-and-MVC